# 2-Banach Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces, banach-fixed-point

Somebody please clear my doubts:

I recently saw an article on "2-Banach Spaces." While reading it, I had few questions (may be simple ones), I just want to get clarified them. The following are the questions:

1. What is the reason for introducing the concept of "2-Banach spaces" though we are already having "Banach spaces" concept? What is so peculiar in "2-Banach spaces"?
2. Are there properties which hold in "2-Banach spaces" but not in "Banach spaces"?
3. Can "2-Banach spaces" be generalized to "n-Banach spaces"?

Comment: Could you give the definition of a 2-Banach space, or mention the paper you are refering to?

Comment: @user342207 probably this paper: [link](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/store/10.1002/mana.19640280102/asset/19640280102_ftp.pdf?v=1&t=irdscf2j&s=38e20eee2bfb40e913abe38fe32855e004b77384) Here is an english paper that introduces it also: [link](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/store/10.1002/mana.19690420104/asset/19690420104_ftp.pdf;jsessionid=479268E35637E847BF2E6CE9B0E5DD6F.f04t03?v=1&t=irds9gb9&s=11d474ba58f81e5f33d15a9afb8638894dd554a3)

Comment: Let X be a real linear space and ||.,.|| be a non-negative real
valued function defined on X x X satisfying the following conditions :
(i) ||x, y|| = 0 if and only if x and y are linearly independent
(ii) ||x, y|| = ||y, x||, for all x, y in X
(iii) ||x, ay|| = |a| ||x, y||, for all x, y in X and a being a real
(iv) ||x, y + z|| <= ||x, y|| + ||x, z||, for all x, y, z in X
Then ||.,.|| is called a 2 - norm and the pair (X; ||.,.||) is called a linear 2-
normed space.

Comment: Here are two papers.                                                                             A. White, 2-Banach spaces, Math. Nachr., 42 (1969) 43-60.
MR0257716(41#2365). Zbl 0185.20003.                                                                                      Mehmet Gürdal, Ahmet Sahiner and Isil Açik, Approximation theory in 2-Banach spaces, Nonlinear Analysis 71, (2009) 1654-1661.